# Emulating Sony devices for Android Studio

Tags: android-emulator

I have a project that requires me to test it on a Sony device. Unfortunately, I don't have a physical device.

Is there a Sony emulator for Android Studio?

Comment: Sony once had a service where you could run your app remote on a physical Sony Xperia device. The service was called "Sony Remote Device Lab Service" but it seems to no longer exist nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Android Emulators are based off the [Google Android Studio SDK Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) and don't contain any Manufacturer proprietary code/API.

The general properties to change when creating a [hardware profile](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#createhp) are screen resolution, screen size and RAM. If needed there are additional [hardware properties](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#createhp) you can configure.

If there is a particular model you need to duplicate, creating an emulator with the same screen resolution, screen size, RAM and OS version would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio only provides Google phones as a built in  hardware profile. But you can create a new hardware profile and customize it accordingly. In the AVD Manager > Create new emulator, On the Hardware page Clone a device and customize it or to create a hardware profile from scratch, click create hardware profile and there you can create it from scratch.